# Siteminder+Coldfusion CFID, CFTOKEN not set

Tags: coldfusion, siteminder

When a user authenticates through siteminder and reaches an application that runs on Coldfusion the CFID and CFTOKEN variables are not set , however when the application is accessed directly without siteminder authentication these variables are set and the site works fine..

Any ideas why this happens / if anyone has faced this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How are they set without SiteMinder?
You may have to tell SiteMInder to send something to ColdFusion in order to have those set